# XDebug, Eclipse and post

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I am trying to debug a registration form.

Is there an easy way to debug a page with post data accompanying the request?

Comment: What problem are you experiencing? Shouldn't be an issue if there is post data

Comment: I don't know how to add post data.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do. Cant you just submit the registration form?

Comment: Thanks, I thought the session stops when I load another page

Comment: See Uras answer in this question - it works for me - yipee !!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471295/how-to-debug-a-dynamic-web-project-with-post-request-in-eclipse-juno

Answer (score 1):

> If you want to debug the “POST” method to a PHP page, then make sure
>   you have “Debug all pages” checked in Run->Open Debug Dialog;PHP Web
>   Page/New Configuration;Advanced Tab. Then you should let the PHP
>   script run to display a web page with a form. When you put the data
>   into the form and submit it, the debugger will now allow you to debug
>   this page with the POST data.

Hope this helps.

Source: [How To Setup a Free PHP Debugger using Eclipse PDT + XDebug](http://robsnotebook.com/php_debugger_pdt_xdebug)