# How to debug a dynamic web project with post request in eclipse juno

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I can debug easily with a Get request (Debug on Server, Tomcat is started and I can proceed easily) as I just need to pass parameter in url but I am not sure how to debug with a post request.

Currently I am using Advanced Rest Client to run the application and checking logs to find any error.[image]
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could use 'curl' or write a test class which perform post request via 'HttpURLConnection'. There are a lot of good examples on SO

Comment: @user: Do you mean to say - I should send the post request to already developed webservice from another class using httpurlconnection and debug it ?? If so then how do I actually debug the post  webservice ???

Answer (score 3):

[Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) is very useful chrome extension for that.

Start the server in debug mode, then send post request via Postman. You can also use any other http methods.

I added a screenshot that shows how to send a post request to local machine with json parameters. [image]

Comment: I wish that I could upvote this many more times. I have not,a s yet, found a way to debug HTTP POST requests to PHP AJAX using Eclipse PDT and this is just perfect & makes it so easy!

Answer (score 1):

Set-up and start Tomcat from Eclispe and set a break point in your POST method.

Then use a client linke [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/), [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/).

Or even bether: Write integration tests which start tomcat and use soemthing like the [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/). You could write a JUnit class rule which starts and stops tomcat for your tests.
This is more initial work, but gives you infinitely repeatable test for continous integration.

Comment: Can I use these tools with eclipse for debugging ? little more information is appreciated

Comment: @Pankaj from soap ui you will post request and debug in eclipse